# simple Python code to request numbers and print the result

Tags: python-3.x

I have been practicing the basics now i am try to do a practice task in uni and i can't seem to find where i am going wrong can anyone point me in the right direction and explain to me what i am doing wrong please , thank you

this is the question 
Write some Python code that requests 2 numbers and prints the result of applying the operators + - * / eg.

```
Please enter your first number:5
Please enter your second number:3

5 + 3 = 8
5 – 3 = 2
5 * 3 = 15
5 / 3 = 1.666666667
```

Test this code with at least ten different values. (Hint:You may need to think about how you manage the types)

and this is my coding

```
    A=  input ("Please enter your first number:")

    B= input ("please enter your second number:")


    A+B

    A-B

    A*B

A/B
```

and i get an error message saying

```
Please enter your first number:5
please enter your second number:3
Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/Users/salv/Documents/PRACTISE PYTHIN.py", line 6, in <module>
      A-B
     TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
     >>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Input will return a string object, and the `-` operator expects two integers. Cast it to an int with `int()`

i.e.

```
A = int(input("Please enter your first number:"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when python reads some user input, it reads it as a string (of type `str`), not as a number (of type `int` in this case).
So what you need to do is to convert the string representation of the number you entered, into a numeric type. This can be done by calling `int()` on your string as follows:

```
users_input = input("Enter a number: ")
A = int(users_input)
```

Consider this:

```
>>> A = input("Enter a number: ")
Enter a number: 5
>>> A
'5'
```

Notice the quotes around `5`. This indicates that it's a string. You could confirm this with the use of `type`

```
>>> type(A)
<class 'str'>
>>> B = int(A)
>>> B
5
```

Note: no quotes around `5`. It's a numeric type. Since it isn't followed by a `.0`, it's not a `float` (floating point decimal type). Rather, it is an `int` (integer type). Again, this can be confirmed with `type`

```
>>> type(B)
<class 'int'>
```